# how to write function in seprate class and use in activity

Tags: android

im using this function in my class below  in same activity and call also in same activity but code is too lengthy so i want to write  decodeFile function in seprate class and use in my my activity how i do  that?? how i write decode function in another class and use in my activity???

```
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, 
    o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Call like this in same activity

```
    if (DataC.getCount() > 0) {
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(root + "/"  + 
    currentFiles[info.position].getName()));
```

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code? plz also add log with question to get more help from us

Comment: make it static inside something like Utils class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an application-wide Utils class in your project.  You can add the decodeFile(File f) method as a public static method:
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
along with any other utility methods you might need throughout your project.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to make the function public static and then access it in the Activity using classname as

```
public class Myclass
{
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) 
    { ... }
}
```

and assuming your class name is `MyClass` call it as

```
if (DataC.getCount() > 0) {
        Bitmap bitmap = MyClass.decodeFile(new File(root + "/"  + 
currentFiles[info.position].getName()));
```

Comment: no i want to write function in seprate class so my Activity class not look so lengthy